# Selenium with Python: First instance of the element is identified but the next occurance is ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have the following Selenium Test for Python/Django application:

```
class EmailRecordsTest(StaticLiveServerTestCase):

    def test_can_store_email_and_retrieve_it_later(self):
        self.browser.get(self.live_server_url)
        emailbox = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='pma-subscribe-form']/input[1]")
        self.assertEqual(emailbox.get_attribute("placeholder"), 'Enter your Email')
        print("tested until here")
        print("The placeholder: ", emailbox.get_attribute("placeholder"))
        print(emailbox)
        emailbox.send_keys('vio@mesmerizing.com')
```

First occurance of emailbox is clearly identified as seen from the print runs and assert Equal for placeholder. The last instance of emailbox.send_keys throws following error:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message:
 Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

Cannot find why the same element become Not Visible when using with send_keys.

The Html code being tested is as below:

```
<!-- Start footer -->
  <footer id="pma-footer">
    <!-- start footer top -->
    <div class="pma-footer-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="pma-footer-top-area">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
              <div class="pma-footer-widget">
                <h4>News letter</h4>
                <p>Get latest update, news & offers</p>
                <form class="pma-subscribe-form">
                  <input id="subscribe-email" type="email" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger btn-md" type="submit">Subscribe!</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end footer top -->
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `find_element` returns element which would be present on the `DOM` no matter it's visible or not and you can get attribute of this element as well but `send_keys` does an action on element and selenium does action only visible element, So you need to be sure before doing action on element that it's visible using `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

emailbox = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "subscribe-email")))

#do your all stuff before send keys 

# now use send_keys
emailbox.send_keys('vio@mesmerizing.com')
```

**Edited** :- If you are still unable to interact with element try using `execute_script()` to set value as below :-

```
emailbox = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "subscribe-email")))

#do your all stuff before send keys 

# now use execute_script
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'vio@mesmerizing.com'", emailbox)
```

Comment: This didnt work, even after giving wait time of 60. It always times out. `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: @Blueice Ok then try to find element using `presence_of_element_located` and use `execute_script()` to set value, try with edited answer and let me know..:)

Comment: The execute_script solution works. What I also observed is for that `execute_script` to work, I dont think we require `WebDriverWait` or `emailbox = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "subscribe-email")))` . That statement is able to locate the emailbox WebElement from finding by xpath.

Comment: @Blueice Yes, but this is the best way to locate an element, but if you don't need it you can simple use `driver.find_element_by_id(..)`instead.:)

Comment: @Blueice if you don't mind , you can mark it as correct answer, if it helped..:)

Answer (score 0):

Another option which worked in this case is that you scroll to the specific element (which was at the bottom of the page)and then use send_keys it works.

```
emailbox = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@class='mu-subscribe-form']/input[1]")
self.browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
emailbox.send_keys('vio@mesmerizing.com')
```